# Access VBA Test for Null in Date Field

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to write  a VBA script to restrict what is displayed in a list box on a form in Access 2010.

I've boiled down the situation to reduce the number of opportunities for problems so this is a simplified version of what I'm doing

```
 strMedicaid = "[MCO] = 'Amerigroup' AND [DateAssigned] Is Null"


 Me.lstMedicaid.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT tblSamples.MedicaidNumber " & _
                        "FROM tblSamples " & _
                        "WHERE " & strMedicaid & _
                        "ORDER BY tblSamples.MedicaidNumber;"
```

DateAssigned is a Date Field. The code returns nothing. No results.

If I do just "[MCO] = 'Amerigroup'" I get the expected results so that's not the problem.

I've tried 'Null'. I've tried 'Is Null'. No difference.

If I go into the Access Query builder and build the SQL below:

```
 SELECT tblSamples.MCO, tblSamples.DateAssigned
 FROM tblSamples
 WHERE (((tblSamples.MCO)="Amerigroup") AND ((tblSamples.DateAssigned) Is Null));
```

It works. I get the results I want/expect.

Please help me out with getting the VBA to return the same results I get through the query builder. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, your code will produce the following string:

```
...WHERE [MCO] = 'Amerigroup' AND [DateAssigned] Is NullORDER BY...
```

**Notice there is no space between the word `Null` and `ORDER BY`**.  This is an easy mistake to make when concatenating strings and using line continuations.  One way to help avoid the mistake is to put a leading space at the beginning of each line:

```
Me.lstMedicaid.RowSource = " SELECT DISTINCT tblSamples.MedicaidNumber " & _
                           " FROM tblSamples " & _
                           " WHERE " & strMedicaid & _
                           " ORDER BY tblSamples.MedicaidNumber;"
```

Comment: It's easy to do.  I recognized it quickly because I've done it several times myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
strMedicaid = "[MCO] = 'Amerigroup' AND [DateAssigned] <> ''"
```